# Is storing the data in H2 database along with the corda vault a good practice?

Tags: corda

While developing the CorDapp, is it a good practice to create schemas to store data in H2 database?
Because it would be an extra effort for a developer whenever there is a need to change the schemas or business requirement changes as it would result in schema change.

Because if we don't create schemas for our data then data retrieval becomes very slow as Querying the vault using schema executes a database query instead of iterating over each state objects.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, nodes store their data in an H2 database. Nodes can also be configured to use PostgreSQL and SQL Server, and we actually suggest not to use the H2 database for production for security, stabilities and other reason. H2 are used in our samples only for demo purpose.

You question consists of another question: should you always write schema? I think the answer is it depends. Does your cordapp needs retrieve the data constantly? Or does your Cordapp can function based on flows only? It is a trade-off.